# PHP $_GET for parameter with plus sign

Tags: php, get

A system we have produces a URL parameter that has a `+` sign within the parameter name. The system produces the URL and changes the spaces to a `+`.

```
blah.com/index.php?f.Record+Type%7CemuRecordLevel=series
```

I can't figure out how to `$_GET` this parameter with PHP.

I've tried

- `$_GET["f_Record+Type|emuRecordLevel"])`
- `$_GET["f_Record%20Type|emuRecordLevel"])`
- `$_GET["f_Record Type|emuRecordLevel"])`

Other URL parameters without the space/plus are working ok.

Is there a substitution I'm meant to make here, in a similar vein to replacing the `.` with a `_`?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` and see how the server receive it. I do think the problem lies with the period in the url

Comment: Encode it with `%2B` - `f_Record%2BType` when sending the URL originally. Really, the system that's generating this URl should `urlencode` it before sending it.

Comment: Non-alphanumeric chars are converted to an `_` underscore. So just like the period, a space (literal plus in the query string) would typically become an underscore too.

Comment: Nice to know @mario. Thank you. I have never make an app having un encoded special chars before, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thanks all, totally forgot about var_dump and @mario nailed it with the underscore..I had assumed it was just a period that needed changing, not all characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quote from the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

Therefore you can access your data like this:

```
$_GET['f_Record_Type|emuRecordLevel'];
```

If you are in doubt, you can use [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see the value of `$_GET`:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```